# What encryption strategy does the Devise gem use for database_authenticable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Just wondering if it used MD5 or what to encrypt passwords. Preparing a tech doc and just want to be thorough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it uses bcrypt.  But is supports others as well